# eaDesign Invoice PDF Generator - Support is blocking bug report

Tags: magento-1.9

We got a problem with the extension "eaDesign Invoice PDF Generator". Unfortunately the developer do not really help. I spend more than 10 hours in finding the bug but now I am stuck and don't now how to fix it. Currently wasted more than 2 hours with contacting support and try to explain in super high detail the bug... without any success... We bought it 5? times and I am kind of p***

Does someone use "eaDesign Invoice PDF Generator" and can confirm the following bug?

Version: Design Invoice PDF Generator 1.0.26
Tried Magento Versions: 1.9.2.1, 1.9.3.2, 1.9.2.4

The extension allows to call spezific tax values. Like if your VAT is 24% and 20% you can call the tax value of 24%.

eg. 100€ value
20% tax => call 20% tax => showin 20€

eg. "{{var tax_tva}}"

This function is not working on all machines and stores where I have tried it. Incuding eaDesigns own Demo store. I send them detailed information and screenshots but they don't confirm the bug. It's just sending nonsene like other things are the reason...

Please find below a screenshot.
[image]

Can someone confirm this is working in his store? I mean explicit not "grandtaxtotal"(!) This is working perfectly. It's just about the marked variable calls.

Answer (score 0):

We got the solution by the developer

- you need to create at least one additional store view
- go to tax rate management
- change title of tax rate eg to "MwSt." or "XY MwSt."
- inside the EA Design tempalte can be used {{var  tax_mwst.}} or {{var  tax_xy_mwst.}}

There is a fix needed in one file. I guess it should be allready added to the offical version on their download page.